# undefined method `tabs' in activeadmin form

Tags: forms, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have trying to use the tabs in activeadmin form , but its throwing the below error

> undefined method `tabs' for ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Form:0x007fab4d672e38

```
form do |f|
    tabs do
      tab 'Tab1' do
       f.inputs do
          f.input :property_name, label: "Property Name"
       end 
      end
      tab 'Tab2' do
       f.inputs do
          f.input :user_name
       end
      end
     end
end
```

please help me to achieve this using activeadmin or any other options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs are not available in the latest gem release (which is at this point 0.6.3). You have to use the main branch from github, so make sure you have this in your `Gemfile`:

`gem "activeadmin", github: "gregbell/active_admin"`

Comment: yup, am using the above mentioned gem , now removed the gem and included gem `'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` tabs working fine.. thanks for the help. so which is the latest gem to use it should support all the activeadmin features.

Comment: 0.6.3 is the latest, but if you want all the features, you'll have to use the github master branch. I have no idea when the next release will be, though.